# Algorithm for optimal assignment of tasks to processors

Tags: algorithm

I am quite new to this field and i a got blocked by this problem:

I have 4 tasks each have a certain duration and a certain deadline. And I have only 3 processors that can execute these tasks. the task deadlines are basically the amount of time within which the execution of the task should start and finish.

```
e.g : 
T1 execution time : (1ms) w deadline (10ms)
T2 execution time : (20ms) w deadline  (1000ms)
T3 execution time : (2ms) w deadline (20ms)
T4 execution time : (4ms) w deadline (100ms)

so T1 must be executed within 10 ms of the start of the exercise.
```

I am looking for an algorithm that lets me optimally assign the tasks to the processors; in order to execute all the tasks in the leat time possible.

is there anything already established or should i start making something on my own?

Comment: This is a traditional scheduling problem. This would be easy to program in a Constraint Programming solver (e.g. IBM CP Optimizer). Alternatively, have a look at machine scheduling problems with due date.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling
This is a well-known problem. But before you do anything too complex ask yourself (1) Could I get close enough to optimal with a simple algorithm (e.g. sort by deadline)? (2) Is N small enough that I could just brute-force it?